# How do I load training data from RASA NLU in a json file

Tags: python, json, chatbot, rasa-nlu

I've been trying to load the training data from RASA NLU load_data() function in a json file to train a chatbot

```
from rasa_nlu.training_data import load_data
training_data = load_data('./training_data.json')
```

*I get this error when I run the above lines:*

Traceback (most recent call last):

File "", line 2, in 
    training_data = load_data('./training_data.json')

File "/opt/anaconda3/lib/python3.7/site-packages/rasa_nlu/training_data/loading.py", line 50, in load_data
    files = utils.list_files(resource_name)

File "/opt/anaconda3/lib/python3.7/site-packages/rasa_nlu/utils/**init**.py", line 103, in list_files
    return [fn for fn in list_directory(path) if os.path.isfile(fn)]

File "/opt/anaconda3/lib/python3.7/site-packages/rasa_nlu/utils/**init**.py", line 95, in list_directory
    "".format(os.path.abspath(path)))

**ValueError: Could not locate the resource '/Users/maniksoni/Documents/ChatBot/training_data.json'.**

Could someone please help me understand the problem here?

*I tried by creating a json file manually in the correct path, but that doesn't work either. I get a different error:*

File "", line 2, in 
    training_data = load_data('./training_data.json')

File "/opt/anaconda3/lib/python3.7/site-packages/rasa_nlu/training_data/loading.py", line 51, in load_data
    data_sets = [_load(f, language) for f in files]

File "/opt/anaconda3/lib/python3.7/site-packages/rasa_nlu/training_data/loading.py", line 51, in 
    data_sets = [_load(f, language) for f in files]

File "/opt/anaconda3/lib/python3.7/site-packages/rasa_nlu/training_data/loading.py", line 108, in _load
    raise ValueError("Unknown data format for file {}".format(filename))

**ValueError: Unknown data format for file ./training_data.json**

Comment: Check the path of your `training_data.json` file. Is it located in `ChatBot` directory?

Comment: Hi Lokesh - I've updated my original post with the error message that I get when I create a json file manually and then execute the code. To answer your question, No, the file is not present in the directory.

Comment: See https://stackoverflow.com/questions/56964918/while-training-using-rasa-nlu-valueerror-unknown-data-format-for-file-x-json

Comment: Thanks for the solution! My problem now is that I can't figure a way to change the encoding of the json file. I'm working on a mac, and I can't find ANSI in the list of available encoding options. So far I have tried the following ways: 1). Created an empty json file using sublime text 2) on command prompt -> iconv -f utf-8 -t ANSI_X3.4-1968 training_data.json > training_data1.json 3). Used text edit and BBEdit to save the file with a different encoding, nut none have ANSI as an option

Comment: The encoding remains unchanged after running the iconv command too:        
 (base) Maniks-MacBook-Pro:ChatBot maniksoni$ **file -I training_data1.json
training_data1.json: inode/x-empty; charset=binary**
(base) Maniks-MacBook-Pro:ChatBot maniksoni$ **file -I training_data.json
training_data.json: inode/x-empty; charset=binary**